# VBA copy and paste only work if I activate the sheet

Tags: vba, copy-paste

I am copying some ranges between sheets and I don't know why it only works when I activate the sheet before I copy or paste them.  This works:

```
s.Activate
s.Range(Cells(2, 8), Cells(lrow, 8)).Copy
d.Activate
d.Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(lrow, 3)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

This does not:

```
s.Range(Cells(2, 8), Cells(lrow, 8)).Copy
d.Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(lrow, 3)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Why does VBA need the sheets to be activated if I've already specified them with the variables "s" and "d"?  Thanks

Comment: you need to qualify ***ALL*** range objects:  `s.Range(s.Cells(2, 8), s.Cells(lrow, 8)).Copy`

Comment: Also as a note, skip the clipboard and assign the values directly.  `d.Range(d.Cells(2, 3), d.Cells(lrow, 3)).Value = s.Range(s.Cells(2, 8), s.Cells(lrow, 8)).Value`

Comment: Thanks Scott.  That is really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when `Range(...)` and `Cells(...)` methods are not qualified, they operate on the *Active Worksheet*.

> s.Activate
>
> s.Range(Cells(2, 8), Cells(lrow, 8)).Copy

If `s` was not the active sheet, you would be requesting from `s` a range of cells that do not belong to it, but to the other, *active* worksheet. Because

```
       Cells(2, 8)     <==>   ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 8) 
       Cells(lrow, 8)  <==>   ActiveSheet.Cells(lrow, 8)
```

To avoid this trouble, *always* qualify your ranges and cells:

```
 s.Range(s.Cells(2, 8), s.Cells(lrow, 8)).Copy
```

This is the correct approach; whenever you find yourself using stuff like `Activate` and `Select`, understand that you are most-likely doing something wrong. In good practice you will almost never need to use this stuff.

Comment: Awesome.  I've run into this issue before, but never known why.  Thanks!