# Excel VBA question - Syntax for Copying an indexed range

Tags: excel, vba

Hi – I am trying to compile data from multiple sheets for a specific condition into one sheet. 
I want this to step through the worksheets from number 5 to x and do the following 
-   Look for rows in which the value in the Source sheet range E13:E37 is blank and copy and paste the values from (RowSource,2) to (RowSource,5) to a Target sheet in  (RowTarget,2) to (RowTarget, 5)
-   Copy and past the value in Source Sheet cell “C2” to each Row Target
I am having 2 problems with the code:
1.  I am getting an error in the copy paste of the range.  I’ve tried a bunch of different syntax and am not getting it right.
2.  It’s not actually stepping through all the sheets 
Can someone please help me? THANK YOU

```
Sub Get_Activities()
    Dim c As Range 'count for blank
    Dim j As Integer 'target sheet row
    Dim w As Integer ' sheet number
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet
    Dim SheetCount As Integer

    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report") 'where the data is going

    j = 4     ' Start copying to row 4 in target sheet

    w = 5     'start at 5th Worksheet in file which should be the first Plant

    If w <= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count Then

    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(w) 'where the data is coming from

    For Each c In Source.Range("E13:E37")   ' Look at all the tasks
        If c = "" Then
         Source.Cells(2, 3).Copy Target.Cells(j, 1)
         Source.Range(Cells(c.Row, 2), Cells(c.Row, 5)).Copy
         Target.Range(Cells(j, 2)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues ' Getting an invalid operator error for j.Row

        j = j + 1
        End If

    Next c

  w = w + 1

 End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue 1 is due to improper or at least issue prone syntax:
You should add the 'Source' identifier in front of both 'Cells'

```
Source.Range(Cells(c.Row, 2), Cells(c.Row, 5)).Copy
```

You should also get rid of the 'Range' for the pasting code, as it is unneeded and is likely causing issues as well. Both of these changes have been done in the code block below.

```
 Target.Range(Cells(j, 2)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

A better description than I can provide on the need for the additional identifiers when using Range and Cells can be found here - 
[VBA copy and paste only work if I activate the sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384018/vba-copy-and-paste-only-work-if-i-activate-the-sheet)

Issue 2 is that you never loop through the sheets, the code ends after the if, I elected to go with a 'Do While' loop for this case, you can choose any looping form you like as long as you loop!

```
Do While w <= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(w) 'where the data is coming from

For Each c In Source.Range("E13:E37")   ' Look at all the tasks
    If c = "" Then
     Source.Cells(2, 3).Copy Target.Cells(j, 1)
     Source.Range(Source.Cells(c.Row, 2), Source.Cells(c.Row, 5)).Copy
     Target.Cells(j, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues ' Getting an invalid operator error for j.Row

    j = j + 1
    End If

Next c

w = w + 1

Loop
```